# How to detect VoIP call events in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, voip

I'm trying to detect whether the user is on a conference call using other applications like Skype/Zoom. How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, UWP is a sandbox application. As a developer, you do not have permission to obtain the status of other applications.

Comment: Hey @RichardZhang-MSFT, thanks for the comment! If I want to know whether there's an VoIP going on in Windows, how can I do it? Not limited to UWP app. Or can I know which app is using the microphone/camera? Thanks!

Comment: I mainly deal with UWP issues. As far as UWP is concerned, if you plan to use VOIP related functions, you can check out [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VoIP). In addition, you cannot know which application is currently using the microphone or camera. You can only determine whether your application can currently use the microphone or camera by requesting permission.